# Break a loop form another method

Tags: java

I'm having two methods, One method (named A) provides loop and sends loop value to another method(named B). If the condition in method B is satisfied, the loop from A should stop. How can I implement it.

```
void A()
{
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
        B(i);
}

void B(int x)
{
    if(x==4)
        //i want to stop the loop of a    
}
```

Comment: You can't do that this way. What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: Im trying a key generation and passing each key value to another method. If the key is correct, the loop should be terminated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could make `B` return a boolean that indicates whether or not the condition was satisfied:

```
void A() {
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        if(B(i))
            break;
}

boolean B(int x) {
    if(x == 4)
        return true; // stop loop
    else
        return false; // keep looping

    // or just "return x == 4;"
}
```

Comment: I know, I'm being a bit picky, but your B method implementation could consist of one line only looking neater :)

Comment: @AndrewMcCoist Yes, I gave the verbose implementation so that I could add those comments, but yes, `return x == 4;` would be the one-liner for that.

Comment: Noticed just a second after having written my comment :)